# Application Verifier 6.2 (x64) AVRF: failed to create verifier log file status C0000022

Tags: windows-store-apps, application-verifier

My Windows Store app keeps getting rejected from certification testing and I managed to reproduce a consequent crash when running appverif's LuaPriv-check. I get this output though:

**AVRF: failed to create verifier log file \??\C:\Users\xx\AppVerifierLogs\yy.exe.0.dat (status C0000022)**

Process Monitor tells me yy.exe got ACCESS DENIED on a CreateFile operation in this folder. I have set full access to all users (the user reported in the log was the same as the owner of the folder). I am running Visual Studio and Application Verifier as Administrator, but this does not seem to apply. What is the correct way of giving user xx full access to this folder on win8? I have attempted to use different log folders for appverify but with no success. Anyone else able to use this tool with Store-apps?

[This post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/whatforum/thread/5ed560c0-76af-401d-8150-8cd1e69d0b8a) describes similar issues. Attempting to run AppVerif –sppath C:\MyLogsLocation as in the suggested workaround gives AVRF: Error: Incorrect image name: <
So does running appverif -enable handles locks -for myapp.exe -sppath c:\MyLogsLocation

Comment: How do you use app verifier with a windows store app?  I have never been able to figure that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a bug in app verifier.
Have a look at these links:

- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5ed560c0-76af-401d-8150-8cd1e69d0b8a/why-app-verifier-can-not-create-log-file?forum=windowssdk
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dougste/archive/2010/01/11/generating-application-verifier-logs-for-web-applications.aspx

Answer (score 0):

0xc000022 is STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED. The process doesn't actually have write permissions, even if it looks like it should.  This [MSDN blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20140414060832/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dougste/archive/2010/01/11/generating-application-verifier-logs-for-web-applications.aspx) explains there is a bug in App Verifier so even if you specify `-sppath` the value won't be honoured unless you first delete the `%WINDIR%\system32\config\AppVerifierLogs\` folder.